# When link is clicked it does not go to the proper link. How to I prevent link from redirecting?

Tags: html

I have an href that has a full link, but is only taking the child pages and adding the to current parent site. I want it to go to the full link in href.

i.e.  Link on test.example.com href=“www.example.com/some_page
Goes to test.example.com/some_page

Comment: can you show us your actual html code

Comment: Please show the example with protocol. href=“www.something.com” is not a valid href. If you have valid hrefs then you likely have a rewrite rule on the server. Also give more information. This sounds like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the protocol:
`<a href="http://..../">LINK</a>`

Comment: Using `//..../` will also work and use whatever protocol the website is using so https://test.example.com/ with //example.com will go to https://example.com and http://test.example.com will go to http://example.com which is more useful for links to subdomains